# change order state on hook with condition

Tags: php, prestashop, hook, orders

I'm developing a module for my Prestashop website and I'm stuck for hours now on a thing. I use Prestashop 1.7.5.1.

**Here is the use case :**

Some products are set in the default category "preorder" who have the ID 21. When a customer buy an article who is in this category, I would like to automatically change the order state ID to the preorder ID. The order state ID for the preorder is 18.

**Here is the code :﻿**

public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params)
    {
        $objOrder = $params['order'];

```
    $products = $objOrder->getProducts();
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        $cat = (int)$product->id_category_default;
        if($cat == 21)
        {
            $history = new OrderHistory();
            $history->id_order = $objOrder->id;
     ﻿﻿       $history->changeIdOrderState(18, $objOrder->id);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, wh﻿ere I can find all the class and method of Prestashop ? for example, where I can find all the variable of the $objOrder above ?

﻿

Thanks a lot for your support :) and have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the variable of Order object inside [prestashop]/classes/order/Order.php class. Here you can find all the variable and function/ methods related to the Order object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful but I still have some issue with my code

Comment: Do you want to change the order state if the product in that order belongs to id category of 21?

Comment: `public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params)
{
    $objOrder = $params['order'];
    $products = $objOrder->getProducts();
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {  
        $objProduct = new Product($product['id_product']);
        $cat = $objProduct->getDefaultCategory();
        if($cat == 21)
        {
            $objOrder->setCurrentState(18, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}`